# employee management syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am creating a code to make a department list of employees for a fictional paper company. I've got most of the code figured out but I'm running across a lot of errors that I am not 100% sure how to fix. I am coding in python and using pycharm. suggestions/help would be appreciated :)

```
class employee:
def __init__(self, name, age, position) -> None:
    """Initializes all employees with name, age, and position attributes"""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
    self.position = position


def display_employees(listOfEmployees):
    """Displays all employees in the company"""
    print()
    print("Employees in Dunder Mifflin are: ")
    print()
    for item listOfEmployees:
        print(item.name + ",", str(item.age) + ",", item.position)

def allocate_department(listOfEmployees):
    """Sorts all employees to departments and returns a list of departments"""
    allocatedList = []
    managementList = []
    salesList = []
    accountantList = p[]
    for employee in listOfEmployees:
        if employee.position == "Manager" or   "Manager" in employee.position
            managementList.append(employee)
        elif employee.position == "Salesperson" or "Salesperson" in employee.position:
            salesList.append(employee)
        elif employee.position == "Accountant" or "Accountant" in employee.position:
            accountantList.append(employee)
        else:
            pass
    allocatedList.append(managementList)
    allocatedList.append(salesList)
    allocatedList.append(accountantList)
    return allocatedList


def display_department_employees(listOfDep):
    """Displays employees in their departments"""
print()
print("The individual employees in each department shown below:")
print("---------------------------------------")
print()
n = 1
    for dep in listOfDep:
        if n == 1:
        print("Management:")
        print("-----------")
        elif n==2:
        print("Salesperson:")
        print("-----------")
        else:
        print("Accountants")
        print("-----------")
    for emp1 in dep:
        print(emp1.name + ",", str(emp1.age) + ",", emp1.position)
    print()
    n += 1

def head_of_department(listOfDep):
    """Finds max age and then sets employee as head"""
    for dep in listOfDep:
        max = 0
        for emp1 in dep:
            if emp1.age > max:
                max = emp1.age
        for emp1 in dep:
            if max == emp1.age:
                emp1.position = "Head" + emp1.position


employeeList = ()
employeeList.append(employee("Michael", 45, "Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Dwight", 40, "Assistant to the Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Jim", 35, "Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Pam", 30, "Receptionist"))
employeeList.append(employee("Angela", 32, "Accountant"))
employeeList.append(employee("Kevin", 42, "Accountant"))
employeeList.append(employee("Stanley", 55, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Andy", 38, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Ryan", 30, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Creed", 55, "Salesperson"))
```

on Im sure I have to change some form listOfEmployees to self instead but for specifically line 14 pycharm is giving me a red line under "listOfEmployees" so im not sure what to do as its asking me to either create a parameter or rename reference and I was sure that I did create a parameter ? im not 1000% sure. This is for a project in class and im trying my best. Thanks for any patience y'all have with this T__T

Comment: Should be ` for item in listOfEmployees:` Also your indentation seems wrong, at least in the question here the first 2 lines are the same level of indentation which can't be right!

Comment: ahck! oh my god thank you so much @JeffUK

Answer (score 1):

There were a lot of indentations issues with your code. Remember, Python is very picky about it. I mostly had to fix indentation issues and some trivial issues that are probably just typos, because you seem to understand the underlying code. When you see a red line, try to hover it and see what Pycharm is trying to tell you. You'll make plenty of these errors, so it's worth learning how to use your tool to hunt these down.

```
class employee:
    def __init__(self, name, age, position) -> None:
        """Initializes all employees with name, age, and position attributes"""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.position = position
        
        
def display_employees(listOfEmployees):
    """Displays all employees in the company"""
    print()
    print("Employees in Dunder Mifflin are: ")
    print()
    for item in listOfEmployees:
        print(item.name + ",", str(item.age) + ",", item.position)
        
def allocate_department(listOfEmployees):
    """Sorts all employees to departments and returns a list of departments"""
    allocatedList = []
    managementList = []
    salesList = []
    accountantList = []
    for employee in listOfEmployees:
        if employee.position == "Manager" or   "Manager" in employee.position:
            managementList.append(employee)
        elif employee.position == "Salesperson" or "Salesperson" in employee.position:
            salesList.append(employee)
        elif employee.position == "Accountant" or "Accountant" in employee.position:
            accountantList.append(employee)
        else:
            pass
    allocatedList.append(managementList)
    allocatedList.append(salesList)
    allocatedList.append(accountantList)
    return allocatedList


def display_department_employees(listOfDep):
    """Displays employees in their departments"""
    print()
    print("The individual employees in each department shown below:")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print()
    n = 1
    for dep in listOfDep:
        if n == 1:
            print("Management:")
            print("-----------")
        elif n==2:
            print("Salesperson:")
            print("-----------")
        else:
            print("Accountants")
            print("-----------")
    for emp1 in dep:
        print(emp1.name + ",", str(emp1.age) + ",", emp1.position)
    print()
    n += 1
    
def head_of_department(listOfDep):
    """Finds max age and then sets employee as head"""
    for dep in listOfDep:
        max = 0
        for emp1 in dep:
            if emp1.age > max:
                max = emp1.age
        for emp1 in dep:
            if max == emp1.age:
                emp1.position = "Head" + emp1.position
                
                
employeeList = []
employeeList.append(employee("Michael", 45, "Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Dwight", 40, "Assistant to the Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Jim", 35, "Manager"))
employeeList.append(employee("Pam", 30, "Receptionist"))
employeeList.append(employee("Angela", 32, "Accountant"))
employeeList.append(employee("Kevin", 42, "Accountant"))
employeeList.append(employee("Stanley", 55, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Andy", 38, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Ryan", 30, "Salesperson"))
employeeList.append(employee("Creed", 55, "Salesperson"))
display_employees(employeeList)
```